# Can't use MSI after renaming it

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registry

I have an MSI for a product that successfully installs it. The MSI also provides functionality to register some properties by rerunning it with appropriate command line arguments.

The issue I'm facing is that if you rename the MSI that you've used to install the program and then try to use it to register properties, it will fail with the following error:

```
Action start 12:52:01: DoStuff.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:645]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: Resolving source to launched-from source.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: Setting launched-from source as last-used.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\Users\user\test\'.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Users\user\test\'.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourcedirProduct property. Its value is '{47F39EB5-1D42-4A68-4657-5B7D13DBF6tR}'.
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: SOURCEDIR ==> C:\Users\user\test\
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {47F39EB5-1D42-4A68-4657-5B7D13DBF6tR}
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Users\user\test\Installer.msi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: Note: 1: 1316 2: C:\Users\user\test\Installer_renamed.msi
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: SECREPAIR: Error determining package source type
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: SECREPAIR: Cleanup the Hash Value
MSI (s) (28:50) [12:52:01:646]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 52457EE5FB8
Action ended 12:52:01: DoStuff. Return value 3.
```

I'm new to the Windows installers and from what I see the cause of it is that path to the original installer is stored in the registries under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\<ID>\SourceList` key and `SECREPAIR` fails because MSI mentioned in the registries no longer exists.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the reference right now, but changing the name of an MSI requires a major upgrade. IIRC, the root cause has to do with how MSIs can be advertised via Group Policy from a network share.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/robmen/why-does-changing-the-name-of-your-msi-file-require-a-major-upgrade and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/changing-the-product-code